# Zend Form Validator Callback: How to exclude a username?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have written one function in User Mapper class `userExist($username)` which `return true` if same username does not exist in my database table. Now I want to use this function in the Add_User_Form class which extends Zend_Form.

I want to use:

```
$username = $this->createElement('text','username');
$username->setLabel('Username:')
         ->addValidator('Callback', true, array('callback'=>userExist???));
```

Can I use mapper class `userExist($username)` function as callback function?
Please let me know if I am doing something wrong with my implementation. I just want to show error messages if a user is already registered and prevent form submission.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a callback validator, you can **use a standard validator**:

```
$element->addValidator('Db_NoRecordExists', true, array('users', 'username'))
```

[Db_NoRecordExists](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html) allows you to check whether a record exists in a specific table of your database.

If a user want to edit his profile, you might want to check if a record exists **except itself**. Then you should use the same validator as follow:

```
$where = array('users', 'username', array('field' => 'username', 'value' => $username));
$element->addValidator('Db_NoRecordExists', true, $where)
```

In these example, `users` is the name of your database table. `username` is your column name and `$username` the username you want to exclude.

Comment: Hey @Liyali I am inside the class that extends zend form abstract. How can I get that value $username? Sorry if silly question.

Comment: What do you mean? I guess you're talking about Zend_Form. `$username`is simply the current user's username, you can pass it to your form using its constructor. Note that you don't need to use this if you're just trying to check weither a user exists or not.

Comment: See I am adding a new user ok. i hv used only if ($form->isValid($request->getPost())) All is handled by this isvalid method. So how can i get entered user name value it add user form class. Can I get it by using $this->getValue('username')

Comment: If you're adding a new user, `$element->addValidator('Db_NoRecordExists', true, array('users', 'username'))
` is enough for your needs. You just need to add this line to your username element, and change 'users' to your **table name** and 'username' to your **column name**.

Comment: hurrreeyy, Its working now. i got error msg "A record matching 'rajan_123' was found". Thank you. I have one more question. at adding new user all form fields we create are blank, but what if I want to edit existing record and load form with form values? Because before this I was using HTML form, not such zend form... Thank you.

Comment: In you controller, after your form instantiation, you can use the [`populate()`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.forms.html) method. populate() takes a param $data which is an array() with a **key** for input names and a **value** for the default input value. e.g.: $data = array('username' => 'rajan_123', 'email' => 'email@example.com', ...).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8348/discussion-between-liyali-and-rajan-rawal)

Answer (score 1):

Bit late but this may be a possible answer to your question.

Date Element example:

I created a date element with a custom Callback validator that calls a method in the same form class.

```
// Date picker from
$datePickerFrom = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('date_picker_from_date');
$datePickerFrom->setRequired(true)
    ->setDecorators($this->elementDecorators)
    ->setLabel('Valid From')
    ->addFilter('StripTags')
    ->addFilter('StringTrim')
    ->setValue(date("d/m/Y",strtotime(Zend_Date::now())))
    ->addValidator('Callback',true, array('callback' => array($this, 'dateCheck'));
$datePickerFrom->getValidator('Callback')->setMessage("'%value%' Cannot be in the past.");
$this->addElement($datePickerFrom);
```

If you have your own class with custom validators in it then you can do this:

```
$myValidatorClass = new \SomeValidaotrClass();
->addValidator('Callback',true, array('callback' => array($myValidatorClass, 'dateCheck'));
```

In the same form class I created the custom validation method:

```
public function dateCheck($value, $elements, $option)
{
    $now = new DateTime();
    $fromDate = new DateTime(str_replace('/', '-', $elements['date_picker_from_date']));        

    if ($fromDate < $now) {
        $this->getElement('date_picker_from_date')->getValidator('Callback')->setMessage("'%value%' Cannot be in the past.");
        return false;
    } else (SomethingElse) {
           $this->getElement('date_picker_from_date')->getValidator('Callback')->setMessage("Some other message.");
    }

    return true;
}
```

Or if you are using your own class:

```
class SomeValidaotrClass
{
    public function dateCheck($value, $elements, $option)
    {
        // Validation code...
    }
}
```

If the methods aren't `public` the Callback will not find them.