# How to create add - edit functionality using just a single zend form?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have created one form that extends zend form. For Adding New Record it works fine. But I want the same form to work for update record. So the form fields get set for the record being edited? What is the best practice for such cases?

Comment: You asked me the same question yesterday, take a look [on my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482594/zend-form-validator-callback-how-to-exclude-a-username) (last comment). Note that in order to make things easier, you should make your database column names match with your form field names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to reuse forms, it's pretty simple:

1. don't put the action in your form, assign the the action in your controller
    `$form->setAction('/path');` (this will also override the action you set in the form)
2. Remove any form elements not required by the current purpose, typically an add form will have a few more elements then an update form. `$form->removeElement('elementName');`
3. Change any labels that need changing. `$form->submit->setLabel('Update');`
4. prepopulate the form with data. `$form->populate('dataArray');`

Then just process the form as usual.

Answer (score 2):

Populate the form in your controller with data from the DB, but if the form is submitted, it will be populated with `$_POST` data from user

```
$entityData = $model->getSomeEntity(); //and perhaps ->toArray() if applicable
$form->populate($entityData);

if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {
    $newData = $form->getValues();
    //$model->update($newData, ...);
}
```